# Is it possible to create a parallel SPI network while using only a single slave select?

Tags: arduino, spi

My background is in mechanical design and this is pretty much my first experience with a more in-depth system control.

I am planning on creating a network of 144 different servos, each controlled by arduino nano and several sensors. I want to send commands to all of them at the same time periodically in an array format that each nano can parse through from an arduino mega, acting as a master.

Since I don't need the ability to single out each servo, would it be possible to create a parallel SPI, but with a single Slave Select? I figured since the rest of the wires for CLK, MOSI, and MISO (which I don't technically need) are shared, SS could be shared as well?

Also, when designing custom pcb, what should I keep in mind to make sure that all 144 are connected?

Comment: MISO - Master In,  Slave Out.  If you don't want communications with a specific slave, then one SS for all works, but MISO must be disconnected on all slaves, except 1. This is a bad idea, but you can.

Comment: Just use RS485 and embed a target address in your data. Append a checksum too.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat I do realize that having the ability to get feedback is great, but I am not entirely sure how I would go about daisy chaining them all. Also, my programming skill is barely good enough to set up a simple master + single slave setup, and I am not so sure if I would be able to accommodate the changes needed. Would I be essentially adding a section that sends the data fed from the master over to the next slave?

Comment: @Andyaka Ok, you're going to have to dumb it down for me haha; could you eli5 what that does and how it's different from daisy chaining / apparently quite terrible brute force parallel?

Comment: Slave Out.  SS would select specific slave,  so it would drive it's output. Otherwise, probable damage to chips. Daisy chaining would require 8 x 144 clocks to transfer same info to all, but each slave, which is intelligent, can provide feedback. Not sure on technical details, but it can work, but it is not a network.  Again, a bad idea.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat For my purpose, I will be updating all servos at the same time, each one governed by a nano and associated set of sensors. Currently I'm not using the MISO anyway (and I don't see much need for it since all the high level decisions will be made using an outside program), so I'm not sure daisy chaining would provide any benefit.

Comment: @StainlessSteelRat -- if it really is unidirectional communication, why would it be a bad idea to select multiple devices? (i mean there may be issues of buffering signal etc, leave that aside)

Comment: @PeteW You have 144 smart devices with no feedback. This to me is a major limitation IF at some future point feedback is needed. As in are all the servos powered on.  Half on, half off = break something.

Answer (score 1):

SPI is a no go for this application. Generally, SPI is used for high speed, on-board communication lines with a total distance of a few meters at most. It is not something you would use to draw out to 144 different network nodes over larger distances, because it would lead to horrible immunity. Particularly so in "noisy" environments where you activate a lot of motors or coils etc.

Professional alternatives to consider in this case is CAN or RS-485. Either comes with rugged differential signals. CAN is overall the more modern and slightly more reliable option, but might restrict the choice of MCU a bit.

On the topic of MCU choice, we don't use Arduinos for (anything, including) industrial control, for the same reason as the surgeons at your local hospital don't use "My little doctor" toy kits for kids when they operate you. Again: EMC, safety, reliability. But also because we'd like to pick the MCU most suitable for the requirement spec, rather than picking a tool first. Also, 8-bitters are horribly slow and hard to program in C, they are a thing of the past.

In this case your favourite flavour of Cortex M with an on-board CAN controller seems like an ideal choice. CAN is particularly nice when broadcasting data to multiple nodes, because it does that by default: every message sent is always sent to every node in the network. It is up to the individual nodes if they should respond to the message identifier or not. You minimize the amount of time multiplexing. Also with CAN being properly standardized, you can buy standard M12 etc 5 pin connectors and cables, no need for re-inventing the wheel.

Comment: CAN or RS-485 are the way to go.  Processor with on-board CAN essential.

Comment: The modules are actually quite small and are right next to each other in a 12 by 12 array that spans less than a meter each side. Would this still be a terrible environment to use SPI? I wasn't sure what other I am planning on implementing custom pcb board to minimize the amount of wires involved, but I am not sure how much noise there would be.

Forgive my ignorance but the only types of communication systems I was aware of was I2C (which cannot handle more than 128 units as I understand) and SPI; I will try to look into RS-485

Comment: @lascooter Really depends on how much noise there will be from the servos. How are they driven, some MOSFET? How are they connected to the PCBs? Regardless, it's gonna be very crude to select 144 SPI nodes with mux addressing or SPI daisy chain. CAN seems like the ideal solution here.

Answer (score 0):

The 144 slaves can be arranged into chain so they act like a single 144 byte shift register. They can't be paralleled, unless each slave has an ID they will respond to, and can tristate their data out pin, so that only the one that is addressed will be able to transmit.

While possible, it is not a good idea, and you might want to take another approach than to have one MCU per slave or SPI bus.

Comment: Each module consists of four sensors, and I figured setting up a mcu for each one would be the easiest way to tackle this. I will look into daisy chaining, but I am having a bit of trouble how to set up the code for it as opposed to the parallel system.